# How to make a view in a UIVIewController in front of its navigationBar?

Tags: view, uinavigationbar

I have a view in my UIViewController, and there are some situations in which I need to move the view up to touch the upper edge of the screen,

but there is a navigationBar, and it is blocking my view,

what I want is to make my moving view on the top of the navigationBar, of course without hiding the navigationBar,

because I know how to hide it, but the best way for me is just to leave the bar staying there.

I tried

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.photoView];
```

but it seems not work, maybe the navigationBar's hierachy is too high?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the navigation bar in from the navigation controller.

What you can do is hide the uinavigationbar (from the controller) and add a uinavigationbar from the resources. This is a view that u can move/hide and not attached to the navigation controller.